# Flutter load ListView item async

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can a ListView item refresh after each async task?

I have 2 collections on firebase that needs to be accessed and please, if there's another way please advise since I'm new in Firebase and Flutter.

My `users` have a collection inside called `favorites` with the `userID` field (same of the document id) and I load the ListView with all the users data BUT only with the ones that match that IDs (to avoid loading for example 1000 users for no reason = $$$).

According my code and my tests on the Run window I get the value of each user but my ListView on the app shows blank. I tried to place a setstate but the app refreshs non-stop.

I tried to create a separated function but simply I can't get it returning the list of document snapshots.

Thank you

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(id).collection('favorites').getDocuments(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  List<DocumentSnapshot> userDocs = [];
                  snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc) async {
                    await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(doc.documentID).get().then((user) {
                      userDocs.add(user);
                    });
                  });
                  return ListView(
                    children: userDocs.map((document) {
                      return buildItem(context, document);
                    }).toList(),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after weeks on this without any help I finally done it.

1. StreamBuilder is getting only the documents on favorites:

   `stream: Firestore.instance.collection('u').document(id).collection('f').snapshots()`
2. ListView.Builder is returning a new Widget (MessageTile Stateful widget)

   `return MessageTile(ctx: context, doc: snapshot.data.documents[index]);`
3. Inside the Statefull widget I'm returning a `FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>` that is fetching ONLY the user matching the userId:

   `future: Firestore.instance.collection('u').document(doc['userId']).get()`

Simple right? ..

Comment: thank you for posting your answer i think its similar to a problem I'm having but can't figure out...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58527613/flutter-listview-from-markers . I have multiple async/await so it's a bit different but i'm hoping your method will work.